# Connect Exchange 2010 with SMS server to send notifications to mobile devices

Tags: exchange-2010, sms

I want to know the way to connect Exchange 2010 to an SMS server to send notifications (new message delivery) to mobile devices when the user receives a new message.

Answer (score 1):

You should check how to send SMS from MS Exchange 2010 with [Ozeki NG SMS Gateway](http://sms-integration.com/p_131-ms-exchange-2010-sms.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OMS (Office Mobile Service), Microsoft has wrote the protocol, but you need to find the OMS provider on the Internet and pay the service.